# How to run OR cucumber tags

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Feature:

```
Feature: Free_CRM_LOGIN_FEATURE

@SmokeTest
Scenario: login scenario
Given User is already on login page
```

Definition:

```
public class testTAGS {

    WebDriver driver;
    @Given ("^User is already on login page$")
    public void User_already_on_login_page(){
        System.out.println("User is already on login page");
    }
```

Runner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/java/Features/testTAGS.feature",
        glue="testTAGSdefintion",
        tags = {"@SmokeTest,@RegrTest"}
      )
```

When I run it, it says "0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.016s
"
Feature file has one scenario with @SmokeTest tag. Runner file has either @SmokeTest or @RegrTest. When i run it, it should run @SmokeTest scenario but it does not. How can I run the scenario with OR tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a recent version of Cucumber try using a tag expression for example: `tags = "@cucumber and not (@gherkin or @zucchini")`

Comment: Write your tags and my tags, both? Can you please provide the complete Cucumber option?